# Passing function in React.js from one function component to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, frontend

I have a function in App component function postaviRutu and I want to pass it to child component SideBar and in that function on click to call that function in App. So far I have done following, it compiles but have some bug that I can not find.
Any help would be great

```
function App() {
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState(4);

    function postaviRutu(){
        console.log("KLIKNUO")
    }

   
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <ApBar></ApBar>
                <Table className="tabela">
                    <tr className="Sidebarr">

                        <td><Sidebar props={postaviRutu}></Sidebar></td>
                    </tr>
                </Table>
            </div>
        );
```

Function Sidebar.js

```
function Sidebar(props) {
    return (
        <div className="Sidebar">
            <ul className="SidebarList">
                <li className="elementi">
                    <div><Button onClick={ props.postaviRutu}>Početna</Button></div>
                </li>
                ...
            </ul></div>
    );
```

Comment: What information does your terminal present?

Comment: what are the bugs?

Comment: @SurajSharma it compiles, so no bugs in terminal. But it doesn't work

Comment: @DiN, I have added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your solution the `postaviRutu` function is assigned to `props` property of Sidebar's `props` object but you're calling `props.postaviRutu` which is `undefined`, instead you should call `props.props`

### App.jsx

```
function App() {
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState(4);

    function postaviRutu(){
        console.log("KLIKNUO")
    }

   
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <ApBar></ApBar>
                <Table className="tabela">
                    <tr className="Sidebarr">

                        <td><Sidebar onClick={postaviRutu}></Sidebar></td>
                    </tr>
                </Table>
            </div>
        );
```

### Sidebar.jsx

```
function Sidebar(props) {
    return (
        <div className="Sidebar">
            <ul className="SidebarList">
                <li className="elementi">
                    <div><Button onClick={props.onClick}>Početna</Button></div>
                </li>
                ...
            </ul></div>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do like following:

```
<Sidebar postaviRutu={postaviRutu}></Sidebar>

function Sidebar(props) {
    return (
        <div className="Sidebar">
            <ul className="SidebarList">
                <li className="elementi">
                    <div><Button onClick={ props.postaviRutu}>Početna</Button></div>
                </li>
                ...
            </ul></div>
    );
```

Comment: I don't see what is this different to mine

Comment: <Sidebar props={postaviRutu}></Sidebar>

Comment: <Sidebar postaviRutu={postaviRutu}></Sidebar>
And this is mine

Answer (score 0):

I believe the mistake your making is passing the function incorrectly to the child component.

If you want to call it the way you passed it you will have to call `props.props`, instead you should pass it as `<td><Sidebar postaviRutu={postaviRutu}></Sidebar></td>`

```
function App() {
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState(4);

    function postaviRutu(){
        console.log("KLIKNUO")
    }

   
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <ApBar></ApBar>
                <Table className="tabela">
                    <tr className="Sidebarr">

-                        <td><Sidebar props={postaviRutu}></Sidebar></td>
+                        <td><Sidebar postaviRutu={postaviRutu}></Sidebar></td>

                    </tr>
                </Table>
            </div>
        );
```